# Allocation and release of a Class

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have one controller class X which has IBAction instance method say dosomething.

I have other class Y which does some calculations and has delegate self.

In this method dosomething an instance of a class Y is created. Now where should be instance of Y released.Is @property the only solution for this.

//this action is in class X

-(IBAction)dosomething:(id)sender
{

Y *y = [[Y alloc]init];

//init method is implemented in Y and does some job as well as its delegates are being called    time to time.
if we release y. it would be a crash. so where is the place to release y. Is @property the solution by creating one time memory and using that. 
Is there any way to release this here only when next time other object is created older would have been destroyed before only when delegates finishes their job after some time.//

//[y release]; its a crash.

}

Comment: Hi ashish. Just a few semantic issues: A class is allocated only once, and it is never "released" or otherwise deallocated until the Objective-C Runtime is taken out of memory AFAIK. So, what you are really wondering about is the allocation and release of **objects**, not **classes**. In other languages (especially those which model classes a prototypes), this distinction is unimportant, but in Objective-C, it is incredibly important: the class is an object too, which manages the features of objects of itself.

Comment: Hi Jonathan thanks. I have few doubts isn't it necessary If class is created such a way it has its objects in it and the class say Y itself is an object for other other class and now it becomes necessary to release the class Y. when multiple objects are being created and destroyed of Y in X.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing,

```
// In the .h file
// declare like this.
Y *y;

// In the .m file

-(IBAction)dosomething:(id)sender {

   if(y== nil)
      y = [[Y alloc]init];

}
```

and in the dealloc method, you can release

```
- (void)dealloc{
  [y release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: if few times this method is being called -(IBAction)dosomething:(id)sender at a time. y wont be nil at that time, so is not that new instances are not getting created simultaneously for few hits on that method.

Answer (score 0):

it seem to me, that the easiest way to solve the problem is to call `Y.delegate = nil` in Y `dealloc` and check whether the `Y.delegate == nil` before calling any of Y.delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You say some job is done in the init method of class Y. Where some delegates need Y's object until the work is done. After which u want to release Y.

So have a property for Y in that delegate and make it retain. release it and set it to nil once ur work is done.

So in X's dosomething() method you can release the Y's instance immediately.
Have this rule in mind, when X needs Y to live until its work is done, it just needs to take ownership.

This is exactly why retain count is maintained in Obj C. So that an object can have multiple owners. When all its owners release the objects only its removed from the memory.

Comment: there are n number of delegates in class Y so, retaining it in delegates wont be feasible I think.

Comment: It doesn't matter actually.. every delegate can hold a retain on the object.. so the retainCount will be equal to the delegate count. And as all of the release.. finally the object will be released.